# Was this answer spam? Should I have flagged it in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam, specific-answer

Trying to improve myself in reviewing.

I have flagged this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35969758/2) as **spam**

I got this:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

The reason I flagged it as spam is because the guy put what looks like a *proper name* at the end of his answer, which looked to me like advertising.

I am wondering what you think about that kind of answer (with no explanations and non-English sentences or proper names) and what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Kemal Atatürk is considered to be the founder of modern Turkey. Kids and their history these days, tsssh ;-) At any rate, the answer contains code which, at a glance, seems like an attempt to answer the question? Spam usually doesn't answer questions ;-) It would be awesome if it would because that would save us all a lot of work! You should have just edited it out (and I have just done so).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I have decent knowledge in history but I really don't care about this :) So what's the point in adding this name at the end of an answer? Is that accepted ? Isn't sounding political ?

Comment: @ThomasG It's not spam, just contains noise to be edited out.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a political statement, but Google translate doesn't give me anything sensical. Perhaps a Turkish speaking contributor can elaborate? The point? *shrug* beats me. Like I said, just edit it out ;-)

Comment: ok thanks; on a side note I wonder why one would downvote my question... is this a stupid question at all ? :)

Comment: Bing translate does a better job and translates it as "M. Kemal ATATÜRK//we wouldn't be Without!", in case anyone was curious. As for the downvote, probably because this is a bit of a no-brainer for more experienced SO members. Don't worry about it too much, it doesn't count for your reputation, and if you're doubting or have questions you're right to bring it up on meta.

Comment: Google Translate suggests to me that the "Olmasa olmazdık" phrase means something like "if not [for him], we would not." So this looks to be akin to the people who sign their posts with praise for a religious deity. Either way, it doesn't seem like spam to me, but just a salutation that should be edited out. If it is spam, it is an awfully clever attempt at hiding it behind what looks like an answer. if you knew that, Thomas, you should have used a custom flag to make sure the mod didn't miss it.

Comment: ok thanks, that's clear.  I don't know (yet) what a _custom flag_ is (shame on me ?) I'll have a look to it

Comment: "in need of moderator intervention," it gives you a text box to type into. Useful when the entire post is just a troll, but masquerades as an answer.

Comment: crystal clear. I'll do that next time

Comment: +1 - For airing this question, getting it discussed and having some good answers (even though they are in comments). I personally would have just edited it, as "signatures" are not allowed (I can't find the exact post that I am referring to, it was probably in a FAQ somewhere), and are generally recommended to be edited out - I think this case could have safely been classified as a signature.

Answer (score 2):

No, that was not spam. This is spam:

> [MyProduct Pt 42](http://example.com)    There you own it. My listing of the most effective 42 younameit supplements. Do not forget that younameit-are much less crucial as hard work and suitable diet and they'll never change them, nevertheless they continue to be valuable and extremely helpful.

[http://spam.example.com/MyProduct-Pt-42/](http://example.com)

and many variations on this same theme. Once you have seen a few, you know them all. If you want to have a chance of seeing some in the wild, lurk a bit in the SOCVR room and look for [Smokey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35350317#35350317) reports.

As others have explained in comments that after some Google/Bing work it became clear it was nothing more then a salutation. You were correct that something was not right about that. You could simply have edited out the salutation, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Flags and specially spam flags are not correct in that case.

Comment: I thought example.com was banned.